# How to create a class that is not an instance of type?

Tags: python, class, metaclass

According to [3.3.3.2. Resolving MRO entries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#resolving-mro-entries):

> If a base that appears in class definition is not an instance of *type*,
> then an _*mro_entries*_ method is searched on it.

So, I suppose there **should** be a way to create a class that is **not** an instance of *type*. But how?

I know only two ways in Python to create a class:

1. A class definition (`class MyClass(...): ...`) creates an instance of *type* or the given metaclass given by the *metaclass* argument (actually, the most derived one from the set including the metaclasses of the bases).
2. A call of *type(name, bases, dict)* creates an instance of *type*.

Is there any other way? How to create a class that is not an instance of type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohh, I think I got it!

There is **no** way to create a **class** that is not an instance of *type*.

But a base does not need to be a **class** - surprisingly, but possible.

So, actually the sentence from the Python docs should be read as:

> If a base is not a class, then an _*mro_entries*_ method is searched
> on it.

And indeed, in [PEP 560](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/#mro-entries) it says:

> If an object that is not a class object appears in the tuple of bases
> of a class definition, then method _*mro_entries*_ is searched on it.

Comment: If  you create a class, and then use it as the meta-class then your second class is not an instance of type - it is an instance of your metaclass.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Then my second class is an instance of my metaclass, right, but it is **also** an instance of _type_ because my meta-class is still a _type_ (aka class). I verified: \__mro_entries__ is **not** called on such a second class if used as a base.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 A class that does **not** derive from *type* cannot be used as metaclass because it's not callable. Something else callable could be provided for metaclass (say a function), but then the Callable has to create and return a class which is **not** an instance of type. This brings us back to the initial question.

Comment: That is True ... If you think the documentation is wrong (i.e. it is impossible to build class which aren't instances of `type` then raise a bug report. You might get an answer as to how this is actually possible, or get the documentation corrected.